# How to receive newly broadcasted transactions immediately with bitcoin-core RPC?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, mempool, broadcast

With `getrawmempool` it gets me txids, however it just dumps the whole mempool on me. This isn't convenient if I want to quickly detect new transactions. Is it possible to only get newly broadcasted transactions?

Is there another way to sort of stream them from bitcoin-core into my program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ZMQ](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/zmq.md) interface to receive a ZMQ notification when a new transaction is received. You can have it give you the txid, the raw transaction, or both.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is **walletnotify**. You can set on bitcoin.conf file.

For example

> walletnotify=/home/process_tx.sh

That will call `/home/process_tx.sh` passing as parameter the transaction hash
Or you can also run bitcoind with using -walletnotify

> bitcoind -walletnotify=/home/process_tx.sh

Comment: As far as I understand, `walletnotify` only notifies of transactions made to the address that belong to that wallet. I'm interested in collecting all transactions that are broadcasted.

Comment: In that case, you should use ZMQ as sugest by @Andrew Chow